# Why isn't strstr finding the substring from a ring buffer?

Tags: c

I have a ring buffer array of characters that is constantly being filled, with data between two positions: counter and counter2. 
I need to extract that data and compare it to a literal string.

I grab the data correctly and place it into the str array but cannot correctly get it to find the string literal I want.
In this case I want to find the string "OK" from:

```
AT
OK
```

Using this code:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 512
volatile int rxn=0; // buffer 'element' counter.
volatile char rx[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
volatile uint8_t rxFlag = 0; 

void getData(){
  int counter, counter2;
  counter=rxn;
///some time has passed
  counter2=rxn;

  char str[1024]={'\0'};

  for (int i=counter ; i!=(counter2) ; i=(i+1)%BUFFER_SIZE){
    str[i]=rx[i];// grab the data
  }
  for (int i=0; i<1024; i++){
    print(str[i]);  // print all the data
  }
  if(strstr(str, "OK") != NULL){
    print("found");  // this never executes.
  }
  }
```

However "OK" is never found. The literal string should be "AT\nOK\n\0" or "AT\nOK\0". Why isn't the code snippet working?

Comment: You copy the data from ring buffer to somewhere in the middle of `str`, unless `counter` is 0. So `str` will start with 0, IOW be an empty string.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see that! Hm, I need to figure out how to get it it copied over correctly then. I've tried strcat but that seemed to give me garbage data.

Comment: My bad I was using strcat wrong! Thank you @hyde

Comment: Modify the `for` loop as follow: `for (int i=counter, j=0 ; i!=(counter2) ; i=(i+1)%BUFFER_SIZE){str[j++]=rx[i];}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // this never gets executed

The problem is not in the way you are calling the `strstr` method, but in the way you are populating `str`.

Run this unit test to be convinced about the method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char str[] ="AT\nOK\n\0"; // Same for 'AT\nOK\0'
  if(strstr(str, "OK") != NULL){
    printf("found");  // will be printed
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As @hyde commented: You copy the data from ring buffer to somewhere in the middle of `str`, unless `counter` is 0. So `str` will start with 0, IOW be an empty string.

Comment: Yes you're right, strstr executes fine this way, it seems my population of str is faulty!